# How do I check if a query table exists in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if QueryTables(1) exists, and if so, delete it.  I already know what code to use to delete it:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

but I'm not sure how to check first that it exists, so that I don't get an error when it tries to delete a query table that doesn't exist.

UPDATE:
I tried using

```
If Not ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1) Is Nothing Then ...
```

And got a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

I get this same error when using the actual name of the query table I'm searching for (called "MonitorData").

Comment: Maybe `If Not ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1) = Nothing Then... `

Comment: I tried this now - it gives me "Compile Error: Invalid use of object" and it highlights the word "Nothing."

Comment: @JacobH you don't `=` compare to `Nothing` - you use the `Is` operator instead, i.e. `If Not {object-expression} Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check count as well

```
If Activesheet.QueryTables.Count > 0 then
    Activesheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
End If
```

Comment: @Ashley - Since this works please mark it as answered by clicking the grey check mark in the top left corner of the answer under the up-down vote arrows.

Comment: @Ashley see (someone answers)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers] in the help center, for what your options are. I've upvoted this answer because the best error handling is *avoiding error conditions in the first place*. This answer deserves a checkmark IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just turn the errors off, run it then turn them back on:

```
on error resume next
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
On error goto 0
```

Comment: Is this a good practice? If the Delete throws an exception does on error goto 0 fire?

Comment: Is this a good practice? Hard to say, philosophically. You want to supress the error - this does that verbatim. To your next question, yes the on error goto 0 fires. On error resume next means that the error is suppressed and the next line fires. In this case, the next line is on error goto 0, which turns errors back on.

Comment: @JacobH if the deletion raises an error (VBA doesn't *throw exceptions*), `On Error GoTo 0` isn't going to fire it. Try & see. This pattern (OERN+potentially-errorring-statement+OEG0) is quite common and useful to know about, particularly in API's that don't give you any way of avoiding to raise an error.

Comment: Oh I see now what you meant by fire. Mat's Mug is right.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked with a few slight variations to shrivallabha.redij' s solution. Also made it clean all my old query tables at the start of the Sub:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries(i).Delete
    Next i
End If
```